# Visual Studio 2008 express on VS 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

Can I install Visual Studio 2008 express edition on top of visual studio 2003 ? Will it cause any problem for existing development environment (VS2003) ?

Comment: I have VS2008,2005 and VC6 installed in my company pc So for I have not gone into any trouble. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had a machine with 2003, 2005 and 2008.
There are only 2 side effects:

1. Each version installs its own .Net FW - but those can exist side by side.
2. The last version to be installed registers file types to itself. Therefore, if you double-click a 2003 .sln file, it will open in 2008 and VS will try to update the project. To avoid that, open VS first, and open the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2008 express edition supports [side-by-side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) install. It shouldn't cause any problems (no warrenty implied!).